# How can I install `scipy` on my pybrain installation?

Tags: python, numpy, pybrain

I am trying to import pybrain to Python on Windows after following installation instructions. So far I've been able to troubleshoot, manage, fix, proceed throughout the process up until this:

> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pybrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg\pybrain\structure\connections\full.py", line 3, in (module)
>
> from scipy import reshape, dot, outer
>
> importError: No module named scipy

I've tried `easy_install scipy`, `easy_install numpy` with no avail. Where should I look to fix this contingency and how?

Answer (score 0):

Installing scipy via `easy_install` and `pip` is (was?) a PITA in Windows, because they try to build themselves from scratch. Just download one of the available full pre-compiled scipy stacks, [from here](http://www.scipy.org/install.html) with full Python installation, or just precompiled packages (scipy and numpy) [from here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Anaconda or Miniconda, use the code:

```
conda install scipy
conda install numpy
```

You should then have scipy and numpy installed!
I personally am using Pyzo running Anaconda.